# Changing the favicon in Flask/Dash

Tags: flask, plotly-dash

Trying to get the `favicon` to load I have followed suggestions from the internet:

```
server = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app =  dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, server=server)

app.css.config.serve_locally = False
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

@server.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    print('Server root path', server.root_path)
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(server.root_path, 'static'),
                               'dice.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

   ...
   app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If I browse to the `favicon`, I see it:

```
http://www.example.com/favicon.ico
```

However, when I browse to

```
http://www.example.com
```

I see the `dash` default icon with it's own description. How do I ensure my own`favicon` loads correctly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To simply change the `favicon` all you need to do is to create a folder called `assets` next to your app.py and place your `favicon.ico` inside of that folder and it will work perfectly.

app.py:

```
import flask
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

server = flask.Flask(__name__)

@server.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello Flask app'

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    server=server,
    routes_pathname_prefix='/dash/'
)

app.layout = html.Div("My Dash app")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here is the docs link for more information: [Dash docs](https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources)

Comment: That works. I had to remove the fancy route code, create the asset folder, make sure the name of the file is favicon.ico. Now I have to figure out how to change the text after the icon.

Comment: The modifications on `app.py` are unnecessary. Just inside a `favicon.ico` inside your `assets` folder.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative used in Dash is:

```
app = dash.Dash()
app._favicon = ("path_to_folder/(your_icon).co")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an "assets" folden and then update the "__favicon" property in your Dash app:

```
app._favicon = "favico.ico"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding for the sake of completeness. Nowadays, it's recommended to use a bundle of icons with different resolutions to please different browsers and ensure the best picture quality. You can produce such a bundle with the help of, say, [realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) Or you simply might want to use a non-standard .png or .svg icon.

For that, you can subclass Dash and add your much desired *link rel* and *meta* tags to its interpolate_index method:

```
import dash

class CustomDash(dash.Dash):
    def interpolate_index(self, **kwargs):
        return '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {metas}
        <title>{title}</title>

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="assets/favicons/site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="assets/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

        {css}
    </head>
    <body>
        {app_entry}
        <footer>
            {config}
            {scripts}
            {renderer}
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
        '''.format(**kwargs)
            
app = CustomDash()
```

Do not forget to place the unzipped bundle into your assets/favicons subfolder!

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to have only one folder named 'assets' with a file named 'favicon.ico'

Answer (score -1):

You can just put `title="My Title"` as an argument when establishing the Dash app instance. i.e.

```
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    title="My Title",
    server=server,
    routes_pathname_prefix='/dash/'
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you clarify why setting a title would have an effect on the favicon?